# Problema al registrar datos en base de datos MYSQL con PHP, error "Illegal string offset"

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy intentando registrar datos de un método de pago en una base de datos de MySQL pero al ingresar los datos en el HTML me manda un error de caracteres incompatibles y no he sido capaz de encontrar el error. adjunto el código, fotografía del mensaje de error y de la base de datos.

**Código de PHP**

```
include 'conifgRegister.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['PAGO']))
{$idusuario= $_POST= session_id();
$NTarjeta= $_POST["NTarjeta"]; 
$CVV= $_POST["CVV"];
$NombreTarjeta= $_POST["Tarjeta"];
$FechaVencimiento= $_POST["Vencimiento"];
$NumeroTelefono= $_POST["Telefono"]; 
    
$query= $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO datospago (IDUSUARIO,NTARJETA,CVV,NOMBRETARJETA,FECHAVENCIMIENTO,NUMEROTELEFONO) VALUES(:idusuario,:ntarjeta,:cvv,:nombretarjeta,:fechavencimiento,:numerotelefono)");
$query->bindParam("idusuario",$idusuario , PDO::PARAM_STR );
$query->bindParam("ntarjeta",$ntarjeta , PDO::PARAM_STR );
$query->bindParam("cvv",$CVV , PDO::PARAM_STR );
$query->bindParam("nombretarjeta",$nombretarjeta , PDO::PARAM_STR );
$query->bindParam("fechavencimiento",$fechavencimiento , PDO::PARAM_STR );
$query->bindParam("numerotelefono",$numerotelefono , PDO::PARAM_STR );

$result=$query->execute();
if($result)
{echo '<p class="success"> Registreado</p>';}
else
    {echo '<p class="error"> NO Registreado</p>';}
}
```

**Código HTML con en la sección de los formularios**

```
<div class="content">
                            <form method="post" action="#">
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Numero de tarjeta</label>
        <input type="text" name="NTarjeta" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>CVV</label>
        <input type="text" name="CVV" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
   <div class="form-element">
        <label>Nombre de tarjeta</label>
        <input type="text" name="NombreTarjeta" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Fecha de vecimiento</label>
        <input type="text" name="FechaVencimiento" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Numero de telefono</label>
        <input type="text" name="NumeroTelefono" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>                                
    
   
   
    <button type="submit" name="PAGO" value="PAGO">Guardar datos</button> 
   
</form>
```

Este es el error que me aparece al momento de registrar.
[image: Error]

Esta es la base de datos que utilizo.
[image: Base de datos]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Fijate que en tu query del insert los nombres de los campos están escritos en mayusculas: INSERT INTO datospago (IDUSUARIO,NTARJETA,CVV,NOMBRET, pero los nombres en la bd están entre mayusculas y minúsculas, te recomiendo que en el insert cambies a los nombres como estén escritos en la bd con mayusculas y minúsculas. El error que te esta mostrando tiene que ver con el tema.

Comment: Como señala @CamiloKent tienes problemas con los nombres de las variables, deben ser iguales porque son case sensitive (distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas), debes unificar eso en todo el script. Adicionalmente, más allá de que parece un ejercicio, nunca hay que guardar datos de tarjetas en la base (por cierto, INT 11 no te alcanzará para guardar los 16 números de una tarjeta, debes usar CHAR 16 y asegurarte de que no lleguen con espacios en blanco)